# Don't understand why string.index("word") isn't working

Tags: python

Is it possible that the method `.index("word")` in python does not work? I have this list:

```
['Viganello\n', 'Monday\n', '06 | 48\n', '06 | 58\n', '07 | 08\n', '07 | 18\n',
 '07 | 28\n', '07 | 38\n', '07 | 48\n', '07 | 58\n', '08 | 08\n', '08 | 18\n',
 '08 | 28\n', '08 | 38\n', '08 | 48\n', '08 | 58\n', '09 | 08\n', '09 | 18\n',
 '09 | 28\n', '09 | 38\n', '09 | 53\n', '10 | 08\n', '10 | 23\n', '10 | 38\n',
 '10 | 53\n'
```

A list of strings. Then I print each string and I ask for the index of character `"|"`. Why does python not find this? Here is my code:

```
f = open("Bus 5 Viganello.txt", 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
d = {}
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace('\n','')
    a = line.index("|")
```

The error is `ValueError: substring not found`. Can you help me?

Comment: In general, if the question is whether your code doesn't work because Python has some hidden bug that no one has yet found, the answer is "no".

Comment: No. The question is "Why in my case this part does not works?"

Comment: The sentence "Is it possible that the method .index("word") in python does not work?" suggests that you believe the problem might be with Python, and not your code. Sorry if I've misinterpreted, but it's not an uncommon sentiment among beginners to naively think that their code must be fine, and the problem must be with Python, or the compiler they are using, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your very first line doesn't have that character:

```
'Viganello\n'
```

Neither does the second:

```
'Monday\n'
```

Only from the third line onwards is that character present:

```
'06 | 48\n'
```

I suspect you want to perhaps split your lines on that character; don't use `str.index()`; you can use `str.split()` instead; it has the added advantage that that will work even if the character is not present in a line. Use:

```
parts = [part.strip() for part in line.split('|')]
```

and you'll get a list of elements from your input line, split on the `|` character, guaranteed. That list might contain just one element, but that shouldn't matter.

If you really must have the index of the `|` character, you can use `str.find()` and test for `-1` to see if it was missing, or use `try..except` to catch the `IndexError`:

```
a = line.find('|')
if a == -1:
    # oops, no such character
```

or

```
try:
    a = line.index('|')
except IndexError:
    # oops, no such character
```

Comment: Ok. Good point. Maybe it is one step more in my project. Thanks man

Comment: aaaaaah sorry man. My connection felt down and I didn't accept your answer :(

Comment: @pp94: not a problem; still glad to have been of help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Some of your strings don't have `|` in them, hence the exception. I'd suggest using [`line.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.find) in place of [`line.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index), and checking the return value for `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line: "Viganello\n" does not have the "|", and raises the ValueError you're getting.

Either check for it before getting the index:

```
for line in lines:
    if "|" in line:
        print(line.index("|"))
```

Or use a try statement to catch the ValueError

Or even easier, use str.find() instead of str.index(), which does not raise the ValueError:

```
for line in lines:
    print(line.find("|"))
```